# What is the intent behind `F[Something[F]]`?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I see a lot of `F[Request[F]]`, `F[Monitor[F]]` and `F[Something[F]]` around. Although I understand the mechanics of how to handle this, I don't have an intuitive understanding of why some effect (`F`) should appear like this (both wrapping around `Something` and appearing inside that `Something`). Insights ?

Comment: Short answer, `Something` will create side effects, so it is parametric over an effect type. Thus `Something[F]`. Then, probably the creation of `Something` is also a side effect _(mainly because something is a shared mutable state)_, thus its creation must also be wrapped over some effect. And for simplicity, we say that both effects will be the same.

Comment: If you are intersted in origin of `F[Something[F]]` you should read about recursioin schemes, `Free`/`Cofree`, tagless final.

Answer (score 4):

A simple HTTP server can be represented with the following function:
Request => Response

However, we commonly need to perform an effectful operation such as retrieving data from database or call external service. Such cases we would define like this:
Request => F[Response]

http4s has own abstraction over Routes (Endpoints) called HttpRoutes[F] and it is type alias for Kleisli[OptionT[F, ?], Request, Response] as mentioned in the documentation.

As we know from cats documentation, Kleisli is just compositions of functions  that return a monadic value like Option[A], Either[L, R], etc.

> One of the most useful properties of functions is that they compose. That is, given a function A => B and a function B => C, we can combine them to create a new function A => C.

In this case http4s's Kleislei takes Request and returns F[Response], simply Request => F[Response]. F is an effect type.

With a bit of modification the above Request and Response types, we get the following:

```
type HttpRoutes[F] = Kleisli[OptionT[F, *], Request[F], Response[F]]
```

An HttpRoutes[F] is declared as a simple series of case statements. Each case statement attempts to match and optionally extract from an incoming Request[F]. The code associated with the first matching case is used to generate a F[Response[F]].

The simplest case statement matches all requests without extracting anything. The right hand side of the request must return a F[Response[F]].

We can see here simple demonstration of F[Response[F]]

```
scala> val getRoot = Request[IO](Method.GET, uri"/")
getRoot: org.http4s.Request[cats.effect.IO] = Request(method=GET, uri=/, headers=Headers())

scala> val io = service.orNotFound.run(getRoot)
io: cats.effect.IO[org.http4s.Response[cats.effect.IO]] = <function1>
```

Here `cats.effect.IO[org.http4s.Response[cats.effect.IO]]` is unresolved yet, this is aync result. It will be resolved in future at some point as simple Future/Promise. And we can enforce it to run:

```
scala> val response = io.unsafeRunSync
response: org.http4s.Response[cats.effect.IO] = Response(status=200, headers=Headers())
```

1. [Kleisli](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html)
2. [Http4s](https://http4s.org/)
3. Practical FP in Scala by Gabriel Volpe

Comment: I really liked this post. To add (I'm quite new to these concepts also) - the effect is `F`, so you're yielding the effect with a `Response[F]`. That being `F[Response[F]]`. `Response[T[_]]` needs the `F` to implement abstract classes and interfaces which also need the underlying type `F` to ensure that the Effect type (`Future`, `Task`, `IO`) which is implemented and yielded at runtime is consistent across the board. I consider it a type safety thing.

Comment: What is the meaning of the inner F exactly ? as in Response[F], what does it says about what a Response[F] is ? and what it does internally ? I have posted a specific question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916337/need-clarification-for-confusing-http4s-message-type-responsef-or-requestf

Answer (score 2):

F[_] is just an abstraction. It can be List or IO of something else with kind * -> *. The main idea that you can define common functions. A good example of this a Functor typeclass and the map function inside this class.
So in your code, you can say that you F is a functor (F[_]: Functor) and after it allows you to use a map function.

Comment: The question was not about what `F[_]` means in general (which your answer is about). But rather what is the intuition about `F[X[F]]` where `F` appears around and inside `X`.

Comment: Oh got this. Sometimes this happens. For example in my code, F[X[F]] appears in module creation. Inner F describes an effect type for module X and outer F shows a type of construction effect. It isn't necessary to use the same effect types inside and outside, you can use F[X[G]], but for simplification F and G considered to be the same, because, in fact, it is an IO in real life.

Comment: I think it would be best to add a documentation about why X[F]. F[X] is well explained. For instance the Resource data type explain it well in it definition https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/resource `def use[B](f: A => F[B]): F[B]`. But it is not obvious what exactly a Response is supposed to do that has an F effect. What Operation does a Response need to do that is side effecting and therefore represented as a external action description. That is the Gap that is missing in the documentation and anywhere else. Resource is somewhat defined as an IO Action, ....

Comment: An action that acquire and Release and use in the process. But what is conceptual a Response then, such that is need to do F stuff ? That conceptual part is nowhere to be found in the documentation.